# Вывести строку в формате: "текст:" (здесь запрос ввода данных) "текст" в Python

Tags: python

Всем привет.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли вывести строку вот в таком формате:

```
Input a letter: > j  # 7 attempts
```

То есть сначала идёт текст, затем запрос на ввод данных и справа текст. То есть текст слева и текст справа уже должен быть до запроса ввода.

Это реально?

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```
print(f'text {input()} text')
```

Comment: Не, не прокатит. Ничего не выведет пока вы данные не введете

Comment: Вот я пробовал через f, не прокатило, поэтому решил спросить.

Answer (score 0):

В первом приближении вот так как-то

```py
attempts = 10
letter = 'j'
while attempts:
    attempts_string = f'# {attempts} attempts'
    back_line = '\b' * (len(attempts_string) + 2)
    if input('input a letter   ' + attempts_string + back_line) == letter:
        break
    attempts -= 1
else:
    print('Attempts is finished')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]